# Visual Studio Exception - extension?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I get the error shown in the screenshot:

*Visual Studio has encoutered and exception.  This may be caused by an extension.*

Any idea?  I recently opened the project in VS2010, and set it to allow Nuget Restore.  Now, I am opening it on a machine with only VS2010.

Update: Here is the meaningless gbbleldygook I see in ActivityLog.xml

> System.IO.IOException: The directory name is invalid. at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError() at System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() at
>   System.Windows.Input.Cursor.LoadFromStream(Stream cursorStream) at
>   System.Windows.Input.Cursor..ctor(Stream cursorStream) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.LeftSelectionMargin.get_RightArrowCursor()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.LeftSelectionMarginProvider.CreateMargin(IWpfTextViewHost
>   textViewHost, IWpfTextViewMargin containerMargin) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.ContainerMargin.b__2(IWpfTextViewMarginProvider
>   mp) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.InstantiateExtension[TExtension,TMetadata,TExtensionInstance](Object
>   errorSource, Lazy`2 provider, Func`2 getter

[image]

Comment: I have updated with the message from the log.

Comment: GetTempFileName() should **never** generate an invalid directory name.  This is a machine setup problem, probably caused by a bad value for the TEMP environment variable.

Comment: Hans - you nailed it! We have frequent problems where one mystery program creates a file called ../Temp/4  and other apps need that folder.  Very frustrating, but this is it.  Please submit an answer if you want the points.

Comment: Thanks Hans - that was the problem for me too. Somehow my TEMP path got messed up. Reset it to a known good path, restarted my machine and everything worked just fine.